# How to close the tooltip programatically in highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with scatter series. I had added a event listener for the chart so that on clicking outside of the tooltip, the tooltip will close. But it is not working it seems.

I am using highchart version 4.2.3.

http://jsfiddle.net/buc3pemq/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: { events: {
                click: function(event) {
                  var $this = this;
                  _.each(this.series[0].points, function(p){ $this.tooltip.refresh(p)});
                }
              }
},
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    series: [
       {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
        type: 'scatter'
    }]
});
```

Comment: You should be able to use this.tooltip.hide() for hiding your tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/buc3pemq/1/

Comment: Hi, I am seeing one issue in this solution. After clicking outside the tooltip is getting closed temporarily but when I am moving the mouse that previously selected tooltip is getting displayed again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you should be able to use tooltip.hide() for hiding tooltip in your chart.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      click: function(event) {
        var $this = this;
        this.tooltip.hide();
      }
    }
  },
```

Live example of hiding tooltip with above method: 
http://jsfiddle.net/buc3pemq/1/

Comment: Hi, I am seeing one issue in this solution. After clicking outside the tooltip is getting closed temporarily but when I am moving the mouse that previously selected tooltip is getting displayed again

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/buc3pemq/2/

Comment: But here the problem is once after clicking outside the the tooltip is getting hidden but when again I am hovering on the same point the tooltip is not getting shown.

Comment: In previous example http://jsfiddle.net/buc3pemq/1/ tooltip was getting shown even if I was moving the mouse far from the actual point. The tooltip should be shown only if we hover on the point.

Comment: No, I had missed that option. Thank you very much. Your last solution is working fine with stickyTracking false :)